# Importing .txt file in R

Tags: r, import

I want to import a txt file that has following pattern:

```
"X1"\"ID_T35.x"\"Produktionsdatum.x"\"Herstellernummer.x"\"Werksnummer.x"\"Fehlerhaft.x"\"Fehlerhaft_Datum.x"\"Fehlerhaft_Fahrleistung.x"\"ID_T35.y"\"Produktionsdatum.y"\"Herstellernummer.y"\"Werksnummer.y"\"Fehlerhaft.y"\"Fehlerhaft_Datum.y"\"Fehlerhaft_Fahrleistung.y""1"\2\"35-217-2173-92"\2008-11-07\"217"\2173\0\NA\0\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"2"\9\"35-217-2173-23"\2008-11-07\"217"\2173\0\NA\0\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"3"\10\"35-217-2173-24"\2008-11-07\"217"\2173\0\NA\0\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"4"\11\"35-217-2173-52"\2008-11-07\"217"\2173\0\NA\0\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"5"\12\"35-217-2173-104"\2008-11-07\"217"\2173\0\NA\0\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"6"\19\"35-217-2173-50"\2008-11-07\"217"\2173\0\NA\0\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"7"\20\"35-217-2173-93"\2008-11-07\"217"\2173\0\NA\0\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"8"\21\"35-217-2173-111"\2008-11-07\"217"\2173\0\NA\0\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"9"\22\"35-217-2173-113"\2008-11-07\"217"\2173\0\NA\0\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"10"\23\"35-217-2173-138"\2008-11-07\"217"\2173\0\NA\0\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"11"\24\"35-217-2173-150"\2008-11-07\"217"\2173\0\NA\0\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"12"\25\"35-217-2173-158"\2008-11-07\"217"\2173\0\NA\0\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"13"\33\"35-217-2173-8"\2008-11-07\"217"\2173\0\NA\0\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"14"\34\"35-217-2173-43"\2008-11-07\"217"\2173\0\NA\0\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"15"\35\"35-217-2173-79"\2008-11-07\"217"\2173\1\2010-04-28\41562.3534246575\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"16"\36\"35-217-2173-102"\2008-11-07\"217"\2173\0\NA\0\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"17"\37\"35-217-2173-117"\2008-11-07\"217"\2173\0\NA\0\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"18"\38\"35-217-2173-139"\2008-11-07\"217"\2173\1\2010-04-28\41562.3534246575\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"19"\40\"35-217-2173-55"\2008-11-07\"217"\2173\0\NA\0\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"20"\41\"35-217-2173-182"\2008-11-08\"217"\2173\1\2010-04-29\41648.7616438356\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"21"\42\"35-217-2173-212"\2008-11-08\"217"\2173\0\NA\0\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"22"\43\"35-217-2173-227"\2008-11-08\"217"\2173\1\2010-04-29\41648.7616438356\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"23"\44\"35-217-2173-283"\2008-11-08\"217"\2173\0\NA\0\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"24"\49\"35-217-2173-41"\2008-11-07\"217"\2173\0\NA\0\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA\NA"25"
```

The backslash indicates a new column up until the string "1". That should be a new row. The dataset should have 818844 rows. The dataset is called Einzelteil_T35. My approach has been this one:

```
library(readr)
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

Einzelteil_T35 <- read_file("Einzelteil_T35.txt") %>%
  str_replace_all(. , "\"\"", ";") %>%
  str_replace_all(. ,"____", "\n" ) %>%    #"_____" means i haven't find a pattern to identify the new row
  fread(text = .) %>%
  as_tibble()
```

I've been thinking about a way of counting backslashes and creating a new row everytime I find the 15th backslash because the 15th backslash is the begining of a new row but I don't find a way. Maybe you can help me with this approach or with something completely different.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code reads the file, converts it to an Nx15 matrix, removes the line number from the last column, uses the first line as header and then converts it to a data.frame.

The only remaining problem is that the conversion to a matrix converted all cell contents to characters. You'll have to manually convert the columns back to numeric.

```
data = paste(scan("data_line.txt",what="character"),collapse='') ## Read the file
dmat = matrix(strsplit(data,"\\\\")[[1]],ncol=15,byrow=T) ## Convert it to a matrix
dmat[,15] = gsub("\".*[0-9]\"","",dmat[,15]) ## Remove the next line number from the values of the last column
colnames(dmat)=dmat[1,] ## Take first line as names
dmat = dmat[-1,] ## Remove first line (as it contained the names)
df = as.data.frame(dmat)
```

EDIT: Fixed the regular expression.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response! There is one issue though: The next line number in the last column does not get removed if the observation is a NA. It works with the first 8 rows. But after that the observations look like this: NA"1, NA"2, NA"3... Since I'm quite new to R I don't really understand how your third line works: you are redefining dmat[,15] with gsub but also set dmat[,15] as data in gsub. I don't understand what is happening under the hood there. Maybe you can help me understanding that part?  (Looking at the gsub documentation didn't help) Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What this line doesis searching for the regular expression pattern: `"numbers"`. When it finds this pattern of numbers in quotation marks, it replaces them with an empty string (`"`). And it does that in all of the cells in the 15th column. It should work. But if you give me the first 20 lines instead of the first 2, I can tinker around with it and probably spot the mistake. I just worked with the data that was here.

Comment: All right, thank you. I updated the dataset to 25 rows I hope it's enough.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I forgot a period in the regular expression. The line should read `dmat[,15]=gsub("\".*[0-9]\"","",dmat[,15])`. Then it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you can be sure that the pattern "1" only ever appears to mark the new row, maybe you can try this?

Edit: I meant without the first pipe.

```
library(readr)
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

Einzelteil_T35 <- read_file("Einzelteil_T35.txt") %>%
  str_replace_all(. ,'\\"1\\"', "\n" ) %>%   
  fread(text = .) %>%
  as_tibble()
```

If not maybe there is a way to make the pattern a bit more specific, for instance if the "" before the new row is always preceded by ".y" or something.

Comment: For each new row the number increases by one, such that the last row would be "818844". Your code throws this error : Error in fread(text = .) : 
  Single column input contains invalid quotes. Self healing only effective when ncol>1

Comment: The first row contains the names of the columns. After that the observations change all the time so there is no pattern in the first column of each row